# Pandas grouping and return result in single line

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have datafram like given below.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['server1', 'NA', 'NA', '2011-03-31'],
        ['server1', '2011-02-22', 'NA', 'NA'],
        ['server1', 'NA', '2011-06-22', 'NA'],
        ['server2', 'NA', 'NA', '2011-12-31'],
        ['server2', 'NA', '2011-02-21', 'NA'],
        ['server3', 'NA', 'NA', '2011-08-29'],
    ], columns=['hostname', 'patch_date1', 'patch_date2', 'patch_date3'])

df
```

I want to group data and show result like below.

```
server1 | 2011-02-22 | 2011-06-22 | 20211-03-31
server2 | NA         | 2011-02-21 | 2011-12-31
server3 | NA         | NA         | 2011-08-29
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `.replace()` and `.groupby()` methods like :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['server1', 'NA', 'NA', '2011-03-31'],
        ['server1', '2011-02-22', 'NA', 'NA'],
        ['server1', 'NA', '2011-06-22', 'NA'],
        ['server2', 'NA', 'NA', '2011-12-31'],
        ['server2', 'NA', '2011-02-21', 'NA'],
        ['server3', 'NA', 'NA', '2011-08-29'],
    ], columns=['hostname', 'patch_date1', 'patch_date2', 'patch_date3'])

df = df.replace('NA', '').groupby('hostname').max().replace('', 'NA') # like this

print(df)
```

output:

```
         patch_date1 patch_date2 patch_date3
hostname                                    
server1   2011-02-22  2011-06-22  2011-03-31
server2           NA  2011-02-21  2011-12-31
server3           NA          NA  2011-08-29
```

Comment: I think he wants to maintain the `'NA'`

Comment: @JeffreyRam got it, I updated the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [**`pandas.DataFrame.first`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first.html#pandas-dataframe-first) combined :

```
import numpy as np

df.replace('NA', np.nan, inplace=True)

out = df.groupby('hostname', as_index=False).first()

out.fillna('NA', inplace=True)
```

##### `>>> print(out)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
df\
    .replace("NA", np.nan)\
    .groupby("hostname")\
    .first()\
    .reset_index()\
    .fillna("NA")
```